# hibernate identifier problem with User creation

Tags: hibernate

I have this problem here : org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: ids for this class must be manually assigned beforeQuery calling save() ...

I saw another topic but I can't understand the answer or if it's the same as me.

Here is my code :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USERS")

public class User {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "loginU")
    private String loginU;

    private String mailU;

    private String pwdU;


    public User(String login, String email, String password) {
        this.loginU = login;
        this.mailU = email;
        this.pwdU = password;
    }
```

```
 /**
     * Crée un utilisateur.
     */
    public User createUser(String login, String email, String password) {
        User user = getUserByLogin(login);
        if (user == null) {
            user = new User(login, email, password);
            em.persist(user);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
        return user;
    }
```

```
public User newUser(String login, String email, String password) {
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        User user = userDAO.createUser(login, email, password);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        return user;
    }
```

I don't understand why hibernate wants a identifier since I'm giving it one with my User constructor ?

Thanks for reading me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missing `@GeneratedValue`

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator="system-uuid")
@GenericGenerator(name="system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
@Column(name = "loginU", nullable = false)
private String loginU;
```

Comment: Even though my login is a string I need an id generated ?

Comment: No not work see my edited answer

Comment: Thanks it resoled the last error but now it's this one :

```javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not execute statement
org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not execute statement
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: value too long for type character varying(25)
```
I only gave you the first line of every error

Comment: I don't understand what you want to say

Comment: I edited my comment is it good now ?

Comment: This is `postgresql` error i don't have knowledge about that but error says you declare `column` with datatype `varying(25) ` and you inserted `>25` character...

Comment: Change `varying(25)` to `Variying(255)` in your database column

Comment: hmm, now I got an error because I asked for not null but hibernate wanted to insert this 
```ff8081817cea7b51017cea7bd8380000, null, null```
So, he's giving me null and null even though I create a user with all three parameters ?
And loginU is ff8081817cea7b51017cea7bd8380000 but I wanted to only have the login inputed in the form on the site

Comment: put `nullable = false` in `@Column` annotation like `@Column(nullable = false)`

Comment: Ok so I found my bug. 
Since the begining my mapping was good BUT in my servlet, I was using ```request.getServletContext().getAttribute()``` instead of ```request.getParameter()```
Sorry for the inconvenience and thanks for helping me :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `@PrePersist` but make sure loginU column length should be 36 characters

```
@PrePersist
public void autofill() {
    this.setLoginU(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
}
```